# Python Text Matching - Synonyms

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, synonym, textmatching

I have two columns in Pandas:  A and B, each of which contains strings of terms.  My objective is to find the entry in column B which is most similar to column A.  I am already using the TF-IDF to do this, but sometimes there are synonyms which do not obviously match e.g. money and currency.

How can I find matches which also include synonyms?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how TF-IDF would be of use here if you are working with individual word pairs.

Anyways, there are two obvious solutions to this.

Use a traditional knowledge base, I would recommend [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) for this use case, it's widely considered a standard in the industry.

The second option would be to use the machine learning algorithm Word2Vec (or a variant like Glove). I would say this is the easiest solution if you use a model with is already trained like the [Google News](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing) one. Look into [Gensim's implementation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) to load the model and compute similarities.